# Append multiple Views after an element on View - Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

```
   addDimensions: function (order_id, counter) {
    this.dimensionsView = new dimensionsView({ el: "#panel-boxes-" + order_id + "_" + counter, id: order_id, counter: counter });
    $("#panel-boxes-" + order_id + "_1").append(this.dimensionsView.render().el);
  }
```

I am trying to append multiple views after a div present in my parent view

But i get the error el is undefined though i have defined the el

My DimensionsView:

```
    var $ = jQuery = require('jquery'),
    Backbone = require('backbone'),
    Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    messagesHandler = require('../../../libs/messages/messagesHandler'),
    dimensionsTemplate = require("../../../templates/order/actions/Dimensions.html");
var DimensionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.id = options.id;
        this.counter = options.counter;
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(dimensionsTemplate({ id: this.id, counter: this.counter }));
    }

});

module.exports = DimensionsView;
```

Error here:

```
 $("#panel-boxes-" + order_id + "_1").append(this.dimensionsView.render().el); //Error here
```

[image]

Comment: The properties `tagName` and `el` are mutually exclusive. You have to define **either**, not both of them. Also `initialize` method is not right place to define these properties .

Answer (score 3):

Currently your `DimensionsView`'s render method doesn't return anything, hence returning `undefined` (default) so `dimensionsView.render().el` is qequivalent to `undefined.el`, which throws error.

You need to return a reference to the view from the `render` method so that you can chain it like `render().el`

try

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html(dimensionsTemplate({ id: this.id, counter: this.counter }));
    return this;
}
```

Comment: i don't get the error anymore but the view doesn't get appended to the element

Comment: @vini hi, did you check whether `$("#panel-boxes-" + order_id + "_1")` is a valid selector using debugger..? also, from what I can see `dimensionsTemplate` seems to be the content of an html file but you're using it like an *underscore template* (or similar template engine)

Comment: i am using handlebars for my templating and yes $("#panel-boxes-" + order_id + "_1") is a valid selector

Comment: @vini also the `el` property requires a valid DOM selector or an element, `el: "panel-boxes-" + order_id + "_" + counter` doesn't look like its valid... if its a class you might be missing `.`  and makes sure it exists in `DOM`, backbone won't create the element if you specify `el` property as per my understanding

Comment: yes i added # still doesn't work. Should i create the el first on my parent view and then render my subviews?

Comment: @vini that is one way of doing it... you can generate the element in parent view, and point childs `el` to it. Else backbone will create a new element based on other properties such as `tagName`, `className` etc, if none specified backbone will create an empty `<div>` by default. In this case you can pass the `order_id` to your child view and generate the id in it...

Comment: The point is, if you specify `el` property backbone expects you to provide an element/pointer to existing element. Else it'll create one for you, which you can modify as you wish via `this.el` inside the view itself...

Comment: Let me try that... Let's c